How do I reference a non-obsolete constructor of DialogDebuggerVisualizer()?
I am using the Microsoft Walkthrough: Writing a Visualizer in C# to learn how to create a custom visualizer. When I modify the DebuggerSide class to inherit from DialogDebuggerVisualizer, I get this warning:

CS0168: 'DialogDebuggerVisualizer.DialogDebuggerVisualizer()' is obsolete. 'Visualizers that target Visual Studio 17.6 or newer should use the other DialogDebuggerVisualizer overload and use a non-legacy formatting policy for improved security.'

But I can't find any information on how exactly to use that other overload.
I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.9.6.
The 'Show Potential Fixes' option only lets me mark the class as 'Obsolete'. It doesn't show me how to access the other DialogDebuggerVisualizer overload mentioned in the warning.
If I add this constructor:
DebuggerSide() {}

the warning remains.
I tried adding this constructor to match the format shown in the DialogDebuggerVisualizer source:
protected DebuggerSide(FormatterPolicy preferredFormatterPolicy) {}

but the warning still remains. Is my only option to mark this as 'Obsolete'? Or is there some way to create a constructor that addresses the comment in the warning?

Obsolete - not "obselete" ...
